# why is alpha value independent of sample size in A/B testing while beta value is dependent?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am recently learning Udacity A/B testing course with this note: http://rpubs.com/superseer/ab_testing.

As I learn the part about "Size vs Power trade-off", the video says "if we increase sample size, alpha value remains the same but beta value decreases".  I get why beta value decreases as the distribution gets narrower, but does anyone know why the alpha value stay unchanged?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha is set by the person doing the analysis. If they set alpha to 0.05, it stays 0.05 no matter what the sample size.  Or another way to think about it, if the statistical test is designed correctly, and the analyst chooses 0.05 as the alpha, the probability that the test will return a type I error --- and the assumptions of the test are met --- is 0.05.